# iPython Notebook and Mathjax labeled equations

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

When I write the following in markdown mode in the iPython notebook:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\dot u &= \pm u^2 +\delta u^3\\
\dot v &= v\\
\dot w &= -w,
\end{split}\label{eq:nf1}
\end{equation}

Equation \eqref{eq:nf1} bla bla bla ...
```

It does not render. It seems that the problem is

```
\label{eq:nf1}
```

since if I take it out, it renders.

I am doing references since at the end of the day I want to convert all I did to latex+PDF. In the PDF output I do receive numbered and well referenced equations, which is what I want. But It would be nice to also have the rendered equation in the iPython Notebook.

Is there a workaround for this? This is, can I render labeled equations in iPython Notebook?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a workaround, but it's not pretty.

In order to have MathJax number equations, you have to add a configuration flag (from [MathJax docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#automatic-equation-numbering)). Configuration flags in IPython are set in `IPython/html/static/notebook/js/mathjaxutils.js` (as of IPython 1.1, at least). It seems like there should be a configuration option to hook into this, but I wasn't able to find one. Instead, I edited this manually:

```
>>> locate mathjaxutils.js
/home/me/.virtualenvs/nengo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/static/notebook/js/mathjaxutils.js
>>> emacs -nw `locate mathjaxutils.js`
```

In that file, modify the `MathJax.Hub.Config` call to include `TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } },`. It should look like:

```
// MathJax loaded                                                             
MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: { equationNumbers: { autoNumber: "AMS" } }, # Add this line
    tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
        processEscapes: true,
        processEnvironments: true
    },
    displayAlign: 'left', // Change this to 'center' to center equations.     
    "HTML-CSS": {
        styles: {'.MathJax_Display': {"margin": 0}}
    }
});
```

Clear your cache and reload the notebook and you should have numbered equations that reference properly.

If you stop here, then rerunning a cell with a labelled equation will cause that equation to stop rendering, because the label already exists. As noted in the comments, there's a workaround for this as well.

In the same file as above, `mathjaxutils.js`, edit the `process_math` function to configure the hub's queue: `hub.Queue( ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX], ["Typeset",hub] );`. It should look like:

```
var process_math = function (i, j, pre_process, math, blocks) {
    var hub = MathJax.Hub;
    hub.Queue( ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX], ["Typeset",hub] );
    ...
```

This allows cells with labelled equations to be rerendered; however, equation numbering will then be local to each cell, meaning that you can't reference equations across cells.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and report back. :)

Comment: So, I have checked @tbekolay 's answer and everything is correct. I can get numbered equations rendered once. [Here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html) it is mentioned how to dynamically modify math (I think). However, I am not that good in coding and related stuff. So, I'll try and report back.

Comment: It seems like getting the numbered equations to update properly needs a bit of work in IPython's internals. Perhaps the best course of action is to make an issue on [IPython's issue tracker](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues).

Comment: I have found [this](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/Labelled-equations-are-not-rendered-when-re-typeset) in github. It appears to be that it is not a problem rather a virtue of mathjax.

Comment: By adding:
    `MathJax.Hub.Queue( 
          ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX], 
          ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]
        );`
after the declaration of `var process_math` in the file `mathjaxutils.js` the problem of re-renderization is solved. As it is implied from the command, different markdown cells will have numbered equations starting in (1). It is a partial and a good enough result for my needs. When converting to latex, everything will look just nice. :)

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect your findings. Should be a pretty complete answer for the current version of IPython.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does refreshing the browser page correctly re-render?  That was my suggestion when I originally implemented this :) https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/2517#issuecomment-9884544

Comment: In my version of Jupyter the javascript file to edit was the minimized version: /notebook/static/notebook/js/main.min.js

Comment: Further to get it to work properly in Jupyter Notebook I had to box equations with \begin{equation} and \end{equation} and not $$  $$

Comment: You could also place `%%javascript` **newline** `MathJax.Hub.Queue( ["resetEquationNumbers",MathJax.InputJax.TeX], ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub] );` into the notebook without having to edit the javascript file. However, you have to rerun that snippet everytime you need to refresh the labels.